# Does the appserver need a bounce everytime the database is bounced?

Tags: java, oracle, datasource, resin

I have my app server resin and oracle database connected. If the db is bounced for any reason, I have to bounce my app server as well to clear the bad connections. Is there any way to get around this? Any property set to the datasource?

Other than FCF...

Comment: Most DB connection pooling technologies have some kind of JMX interface through which you can reset the connections without bouncing the app. I suspect the Resin Admin Console mentioned below sits over a JMX interface to Resin. The lower level interface may be useful if you want to script your bounce.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Resin Administration Console to tell Resin the database connections are stale

http://www.caucho.com/resin/admin/resin-admin-console.xtp